# VBA Script Error After Updating to Office 2016 (CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList"))

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, arraylist

I wrote a script that was working fine when using an older version of Office, but since I upgraded to 2016, I get a runtime error.  The debugging leads me to the line:

```
Set chemicals = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the error.

Comment: You may need to install the DLLs for that object again.

Comment: ERik, it is a Runt-time error '-214623576 (80131700)':  Automation Error.

Comment: Scott, what should I search for online in order to do that?  I am unfamiliar with the process.

Comment: That line of code produces no errors on my Office 2016 implementation. We won't be able to help you without more information -- it isn't an error with the statement.

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption of "better late than never" for an answer, it appears System.Collections support is not available in .NET versions after 3.5.  You specifically need the .NET 3.5 version installed to use System.Collections.ArrayList.